# Android ContentResolver bulkInsert() resulting in duplicated records

Tags: android, sqlite, bulkinsert, android-contentresolver

My app downloads a database from the server to populate the local database using `contentResolver.bulkInsert()`. Normally, everything works fine.

However, if the app is closed partway through the initial operation and the app is restarted, I end up with duplicate records in the database. This is despite my table having an `_id integer PRIMARY KEY` column.

I have followed the execution with a debugger and can confirm that the call to `contentResolver.bulkInsert()` succeeds for the initial attempt and **it also succeeds for the second attempt** - but I would have expected it to fail the second time as the app would be trying to insert `_id` values in a unique column that already exist.

Can anyone advise why `bulkInsert` does not fail when asked to insert duplicate `_id`s and what would be a good workaround?

Comment: Within the bulkInsert documentation it says _This function make no guarantees about the atomicity of the insertions_. Which, I believe, means the exact behaviour you are seeing. Is it possible to clear the db before second bulkInsert takes place?

Comment: Cheers. I'd read that and looked up `atomicity` - "In an atomic transaction, a series of database operations either all occur, or nothing occurs." - so I don't think that accounts for the duplications. Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_%28database_systems%29

Comment: I think clearing the database may be a good bet. The alternative I'm testing right now is to attempt an individual `update` for each received record (then, if that fails, doing an `insert` for each one) but it is unbelievably slow (not helped with there being over 20,000 records).

Comment: As for atomicity, I'm not a db expert, but I was mainly wondering does bulkInsert atomicity (or lack of it) cause trouble with existing rows/ids (not only the bulk insertion contents itself). I.e for the sake of optimisation they might turn _id checks off until bulk operation finishes.